# "invalid index to scalar variable." when trying to evaluate a function taking an array of two entries over a meshgrid

Tags: python, arrays

I'm coding a function taking in an array of shape (2,) and performing a simple operation:

```
def simpfunc(x):
    return x[1]-x[0]
```

I would now like to evaluate this function over a large quantity of values, created by a meshgrid. To this end, I apply the following (as I wish to avoid for loops):

```
newfunc=vectorize(simpfunc)
G=array(meshgrid(linspace(0,5,5),linspace(0,5,5))).T
```

The array G is a large matrix (or I suppose a tensor), where each individual entry is an array containing two values. I would like to evaluate simpfunc over these (2,) arrays, producing a matrix with the calculated values. So I do the following:

```
newfunc(G)# IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

I have previously used vectorize to evaluate a function over vectors, but now I suppose the matrix, along with the sub-matirces are giving me some trouble.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `G` is a 3-dimensional array (shape 5,5,2), but you do not want `vectorize` to iterate through all the dimensions, only the first two, to output a 2-dimensional array - where the input to your `simpfunc` function is sub-array rather than a single element.

The [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) for `np.vectorize` states that

> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for
> performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

This being the case, if it is not doing exactly what you want, I would suggest using an explicit `for` loop to do what you want:

```
output = np.zeros(G.shape[:-1], dtype=G.dtype)
for indices, value in np.ndenumerate(output):
    output[indices] = simpfunc(G[indices])
```

The solution generalizes to however many dimensions you want included in your output, by changing the `-1` to some other number.

Note that `np.ndenumerate` will generate a sequence of 2-tuples of `indices, value`, where the `indices` will be `(0, 0)`, `(0, 1)`, etc on successive iterations, and the `value` is the corresponding value in the array (in fact here it is always zero, because we initialized `output` using `np.zeros`, and is not used, so you could use `_` instead in place of `value` for the variable name in this code if you prefer).

---

(By the way, in this specific case, you could implement the solution without a loop, just as `G[:,:,1] - G[:,:,0]`, but I am assuming here that `simpfunc` is just a simple example and that the real problem that you want to solve is not amenable to that sort of solution.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, you're completely right, simpfunc is a boiled down example, I should have clarified.